# data table creating column using a function vs the function on a single entry give different result

Tags: r, data.table

I found a case that calling a self-defined function on a column of data table gives me different results compared with calling the function on a single value of that column, as illustrated in the code. Can anyone help me to understand why? What should I do to make these two results the same?

```
SLOTS = list(c(2,3))
in_schedule <- function(hour) {
    for (slot in SLOTS) {
        if (slot[1] <= hour && hour <= slot[2]) {
            return(TRUE)
        }
    }
    return(FALSE)
}

dt <- data.table(hour=1:3)

dt[,test:=in_schedule(hour)]

print(dt)

print(in_schedule(dt[2, hour])) # TRUE
```

Expected values
dt$test should be FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, but the actual values are all FALSE.

Comment: The calculation needs to be run separately for each row.  `dt[,test:=in_schedule(hour), by = 1:nrow(dt)]`

Comment: Thank you, it is correct! I'm trying to understand the cause of original code. If in_schedule() is treated as an aggregation function such as sum(), why the length of the resulted dt remain unchanged? Also for a function`equal2 <- function(hour) {return(hour==2)}`, why `dt[,test:=equal2(hour)]` works without 'by' each row?

Comment: As written, the function only works if the argument, `hour`, is scalar.

Comment: I think just `dt[, test := hour %between% SLOTS[[1]]]` should do?